# Should you store Twitter OAuth oauth_token and oauth_token_secret?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to implement a "Login with twitter" functionality into my site and I've been digging up some tutorials on it.

Correct me if I'm wrong, the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret values changes whenever a user requests for them. Also I noticed that there isn't any practical use for the stored oauth_token and oauth_token_secret

As such is it necessary to store and update oauth_token and oauth_token_secret frequently in the database?

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow :) Enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're correct that the OAuth tokens may change if you request them again -- but if you *don't* request them again, they don't expire for a very long time. Therefore, the best strategy is to request OAuth tokens **once** when your user registers, store them in the database, and **keep using the same ones, without requesting new ones the next time they sign in**.

Of course, when you make a call later, you may find that the OAuth tokens are now rejected. This can happen for a number of reasons, most likely the user has revoked access from the Twitter settings page. At *that* time you should request a new set and overwrite the old ones. But it is unnecessary to do so unless the old ones stop working.

Comment: If your identifying users by the `oauth_token` they give but it changes then how do you link a user to an account on your site?

Comment: I think it is ok to store the credentials in JWT as long as JWT is stored as http-only cookie for preventing XSS. Am I right?